# Presentations of $D_8$ using permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-presentation

I fond a lot of examples using presentation of  $D_8$ by generators which are permutations of $S_4$.

1) How many presentations could be found?

2) Could it be presented by permutations of $S_5$ or any different group?

Thanks for advance

Comment: What counts as different presentations?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft they don´t look the same!

Comment: Then there will be infinitely many presentations, since I can just keep adding new relations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It´s not like one is equipped with more relationd than the other, it´s about seeing a different sets of generators plus different sets of relators, and by different I mean looks different not just sized differently

Comment: I think you may want to look up the definition of a presentation, because it does mean what you seem to be using it to mean here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you, But there is another thing, on what base(s) one can add a new relations? (from your second comment)

Comment: If $s$ is some element of order $2$, then we can just add all the relations $s^{2n}$ one at a time.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Many thanks, I wonder if there are other "technics"?

Comment: For the second question since $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n \geq 4$. Then $D_8$ can be presented by any $S_n$ for $n \geq4$.

Comment: I don't  understand the question. What exactly do you mean a presentation of a group by generators which are permutations of $S_4$? The generators in a group presentation like $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^3=1 \rangle$ are just abstract symbols - they are not permutations.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I mean  presentation like $<(1,2,3,4),(1,3)>$; I believe it´s presentation by permutations!

Comment: That is not a presentation. A presentation is a set of generators together with a set of defining relations or relators You need to use standard terminology or else people will not understand your question. It is clear that TobiasKildecroft thought you were referring to presentations with generators and relations.

Comment: @DerekHolt It´s  equipped with a set of  relative orders $R=[3,2,2]$, which makes $G$ a finitely presented group, am I right?

Comment: What is $G$? It depends on exactly what you mean by "finitely presented group". Every finite group is isomorphic to a group defined by a finite presentation. In any case $\langle (1,2,3,4), (1,4) \rangle$ is a subgroup of $S_4$, it is not a presentation. I have no idea what you mean by relative orders $[3,2,2]$.

Comment: It means orders of elements of the polycyclic generating sequence of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the OP is asking.However reading the comments I suspect what they mean may be along the lines of *how many subsets of $D_{8}$ generate the full group*. I will provide an answer here so the question does not remain listed as unanswered forever...

There are 255 non empty subsets of the elements of $D_8$. Looking at the groups these subsets generate, 216 of them generate all of $D_{8}$.

The OPs second question seems to be about realising $D_8$ as a subgroup of a permutation group. They assert that you can generate $D_8$ with permutations from $S_4$. 
Indeed this is true, for instance $\langle (3,4), (1,4)(2,3) \rangle $. 
They then seem to ask can we do the same thing with permutations from $S_{5}$. 
First, we could just see these elements as living in $S_{5}$ instead of $S_{4}$. However perhaps what the OP means is something like $\langle (3,5), (1,5)(2,3) \rangle $.

To the OP, if this has not suitably addressed your question, please update the question with more clarification.